# pythonでffprobeのアウトプットを表示させない方法

Tags: python

Pythonで

```
res = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',target_file])
```

のようにffprobeのアウトアプットをresに入れて、必要な部分をフィルタして表示させようと思っています。

しかし、このコマンドを実行した際に標準出力でも実行結果が表示されてしまいます。
こちら標準出力を制限（出さない）方法はあるのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: ffprobe コマンドの man を眺めると、`By default the program logs to stderr.` と書かれていますので、stderr を取り込む必要があるのではないでしょうか。`res = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',target_file], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: 補足ですが、[ffprobeのドキュメント](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)によると、`-hide_banner`を付けて実行すと、コピーライトやビルドオプションなどが表示されないのでフィルタリングが容易になると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3.7の場合は、`run()`関数を使って以下のように簡単にできます。

```
res = subprocess.run(['/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',target_file], capture_output=True)
```